# Operation timed out with docker daemon and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, docker, daemon

I have this error when I run this command  mvn spring-boot:build-image:

```
Connection to the Docker daemon at '192.168.59.103:2376' failed with error "Connect to 192.168.59.103:2376 [/192.168.59.103] failed: Operation timed out"; ensure the Docker daemon is running and accessible
```

Any idea on how I can solve it?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Probably you have some error with Docker installation. Try run ```docker ps``` on your machine.

Comment: I have this : Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://192.168.59.103:2376. Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: I found the problem I had config related to boot2docker